# Conditional Swap of cells contents in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering, given 3 columns in an excel file, how to  conditionally swap the content of the first 2 columns given the values of the third one.

A    B     C

a  1   y

b  2   n

c  3   y

d  4  y

e 5  n

What I want to do is: whenever there is a row containing the value "y" in the C columns, I want to swap the values in the columns A and B of the same row.

Is there no other way than a VBA?

Hope  the problem is clear.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: You cannot do this with Excel formulas only, without some extra "holding" cells.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 ways to do that:

1. Create 2 columns where you insert a simple function like
   `=IF(C="something", B, A)` and the opposite (A, B) on the other
   column. This will do the switch as you want and then you can
   copy-paste values onto the columns and delete your temporary
   columns.
2. Use a simple swap algorithm inside an `if-statement` itself inside a loop. This should be very straightforward if you have very basic knowledge of VBA. If you don't have that knowledge then go look it up on the internetz.

What the general feel of the code should be:

```
Dim cell as Range
Dim temp as string
for each cell in Range("C2:C" & Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row)
    if cell.value = "something" then
        temp = cell.offset(0, -1).value
        cell.offset(0, -1).value = cell.offset(0, -2).value
        cell.offset(0, -2).value = temp
    end if
next cell
```